# Create a secure configuration file for zsh scripts

Tags: linux, shell-script, zsh, amazon-linux

I want to store some default variables for a zsh shell script that I'm working on. I know that using a `source` line in my script would work, but wouldn't be the most secure method.

To ensure maximum compatibility for all of my users, is there a way using the tools available by default in zsh (on Amazon Linux 2, for specifics) to securely read lines from a text file and extract a set of preset variables from the config file?

While I know the text file itself won't be hashed, that's not my issue. My goal is simply to avoid the possibility of someone inserting malicious code into the config file and having it processed by the script.

Comment: Is that a config file for the shell session in general (like `.zshrc` and such), or for some other tool you provide? I.e. can we use a script of some shell commands to read the config file?

Comment: Also, what's the threat you need to protect against? If an attacker has access to the configuration file to modify it, they could presumably also modify other files in that user's home directory, and add malicious code to the shell's startup files, or add a hostile program as `~/bin/ls` and add `~/bin` to `PATH`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a significant threat - my coworkers and I are working from within a VPN, so technically, no one outside the organization should have access to even view files, much less edit them. However, I am simply trying to following best programming practices and not write something unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any functionality in zsh that would facilitate this beyond the string processing facilities offered by [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion).

Here's some code that parses KEY=VALUE lines into the associative array `config` with the following constraints:

- Keys may only contain ASCII letters, digits and underscore. Keys may not start with a digit and may not be empty.
- Values may contain any byte string except newlines and null bytes. Note that this may include invalid sequences in a multibyte encoding such as UTF-8.
- Blank lines (lines containing only ASCII horizontal whitespace) and comment lines (lines starting with whitespace and a `#`) are ignored.
- There is no expansion of any kind: no variable substitution, no quoting, no whitespace elimination.

```
function parse_config {
  emulate -LR zsh
  setopt extended_glob
  local n=0 line lines
  local LC_ALL=C
  lines=("${(@f)$(<$1)}")
  for line in "${(@)lines}"; do
    ((++n))
    line=${line##[$' \t']##}
    if [[ -z $line || $line == \#* ]]; then
      continue
    elif [[ $line = *$'\0'* ]]; then
      echo >&2 "$1:$n:Null character in configuration file"
      config=()
      return 1
    elif [[ $line == [A-Z_a-z][0-9A-Z_a-z]#\=* ]]; then
      config[${line%%=*}]=${line#*=}
    else
      echo >&2 "$1:$n:Syntax error in configuration file"
      config=()
      return 1
    fi
  done
}
```

To call this function:

```
set -e
typeset -A config
parse_config /path/to/config/file

echo "Configuration dump:"
for k in ${(ko)config}; do
  print -lr "$k=$config[$k]"
done
```